# Template literal - getting error from API

Tags: reactjs, graphql

So i have a method that searches for anime by name, API is graphQL.
Here's the important part of the query

```
const searchQuery = this.state.searchString;

var query = `query Search{
  # the rest of the query omitted for brevity
    media(type:ANIME, search: ${searchQuery} ){
  # ... 
}
`
```

I'm getting two types of errors in response, first is when search string consists of multiple words separated by spaces - "Syntax Error: Expected :, found )"

Second when i search for single word - "Field "media" argument "search" requires type String, found naruto."

What is the problem here?

You can see full code here - https://github.com/red4211/react-anime-search , app deployed to github pages, search API response goes to console - https://red4211.github.io/react-anime-search/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that given some query like "naruto", your current code results in the following text:

```
media(type:ANIME, search: naruto ) {
```

This is not valid syntax since String literals should be surrounded by double quotes (`"`).

Don't use string interpolation to provide dynamic values to the query. These should always be expressed as [variables](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Language.Variables) and included as a separate object inside your request alongside `query`.

You need to define the variable as part of your operation, providing the appropriate type

```
var query = `query Search ($searchQuery: String!) {
```

then you can use the variable anywhere inside the operation:

```
media(type:ANIME, search: $searchQuery) {
```

Now just pass the variable value along with your request.

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  query,
  variables: {
    searchQuery,
  }
})
```

Note that the variable name is prefixed with a `$` inside the GraphQL document, but outside of it, we don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

media() looks like a function, so in that case the correct syntax would be:

```
media(type="ANIME", search=searchQuery)
```

or if the argument of media() is an object

```
media({type: "ANIME", search: searchQuery})
```

Also, you don't need to use ${} around searchQuery since searchQuery is already a string. The usage for that would be something like

```
`${searchString}` or `foo${searchString}bar`
```

using the `` around the ${} utility to represent a string and its variable inside the string literal.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This wasn't clear from the original question but `media` refers to a field inside the query that's being sent, which is itself a template string. I've edited the question to better reflect the OP's actual code. This answer doesn't really make sense in light of the actual context.